# In my react app, input type radio does not show as checked even though props checked is true

Tags: reactjs

In a form I have a simple radio button group with two controlled inputs. By default the No option is checked, by setting the default state of Accepted to "false". This works, but the problem I have is when selecting the Yes option, the radio button does not appear as being checked, when you click it. I have to click it another time before it appears as being checked.

Using the react inspector in Chrome the prop checked is actually set to true.

Hope my question makes sense.

Note: I found other posts with similar issue where the solution was to remove a preventDefault in the onChange function, but I have none.

My jsx in render method:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="Accepted" value="true" onChange={this.onChange} checked={this.state.Accepted === "true"} /> Yes</label> 
<label><input type="radio" name="Accepted" value="false" onChange={this.onChange} checked={this.state.Accepted === "false"} />No</label>
```

The onChange function looks like this:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

The state is initialized it a constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        Accepted: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the second radiobutton also disabled only on second click?

Comment: This might be bcoz initially the state doesnt have any value. Can you set a value in constructor in check?

Comment: How are you initialising the state? wrapping in the form tag might solve it, but in my opinion you can do it without the form.

Comment: Also, why are you comparing `this.state.Accepted` with a string and not with a bool?

Comment: I tried with bool, but e.target.value returns a string even if I set value={true}

Comment: yes, just convert it to bool like this: `[e.target.name]: e.target.value === 'true'`

Comment: Of course you don't need to convert it and use bools, but it looks weird if you use 'true' as a string... set a different value, like 'accepted' and 'notAccepted' or something like that.

Comment: You are right. It does look weird. Will convert to bool. Don't know why I didn't think of that :)

Comment: Just deleted my own answer. Turned out I had the form tags but at a higher level. Form in a form is not permitted. So I still have the problem.

Comment: I just added how I initialise state to my original post